# POST Statement Python Requests

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I have connection issues due to the Error 403, which is why the Website thinks that I am a Bot. I tried to include my Header in the POST Statement, but I am doing something wrong. Thanks for your help in advance :)

Code:

```
from requests import HTTPError
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
   user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
   headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
   site = s.get("https://www.instagram.com")
   try:
      site = s.get("https://www.instagram.com", headers=headers)
      site.raise_for_status()
   except HTTPError as http_err:
      print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  
   except Exception as err:
      print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  
   else:
      print('Successfully opened Webpage!')

   bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
   login_data = {"username":"test","password":"test"}

   try:
      response = s.post("https://www.instagram.com",login_data, None, headers)
      response.raise_for_status()
   except HTTPError as http_err:
      print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  
   except Exception as err:
      print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  
   else:
      print('Successfully logged in!')

   home_page = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/")
```

Comment: I bet the login page runs a captcha or several, and you don't pass it. They don't want scripts using their frontend API, and actively prevent it.

Comment: [This might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916975/8805293)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Instagram API, because the regular UI has usually functions to block bots.

See https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: Ok will do :) Thx for the Tipp